# Error on Access 2007 when trying to open tables which have been linked to Share Point with Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, ms-office

I have this Access 2007 database, which I can work fine with on both Access 2007 and 2013. I have Access 2013, my client has Access 2007.

I have moved my tables to a sharepoint site using my version of Access (2013). When I open the file on my client PC (Access 2007) I get an error when I try to open a table: "The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Object name'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly."

Before I move the tables to sharepoint, I can use the database on both versions of Access. After doing it, I cant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To work around this problem, programmatically delete the table relationships before you use the RefreshLink method to update the linked table."

Source:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926526/en-gb